# How to fetch the subarray values in object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongodb

I am using nested collections in mongodb. I am fetching all the data from mongodb through angularjs.

my code is shown below

```
       $http.get('/Unitget').then(function (response) {
        UnitDetails = $scope.UnitDetails  = response.data;
        UnitDetails.forEach(function (element) {
         var c = element.Beds_Details;  // test purpose
           type1_Bed += element.Beds_Details[0].type1_Bed ;
           type2_Bed += element.Beds_Details[0].type2_Bed ;
           type3_Bed += element.Beds_Details[0].type3_Bed ;
           type4_Bed += element.Beds_Details[0].type4_Bed ;
           type5_Bed += element.Beds_Details[0].type5_Bed ;
    }
    }
```

But here `element.Beds_Details[0].type1_Bed` is not getting any values if I removed that ***"[0]"*** then it is showing `undefined`. If I assign *Beds_Details* to another variable it is assigning correctly as a object.

My sample record of my collection is as below

```
    "UnitId": "59225fd86ea6863028aba8b1",    //unique id
    "UnitName": "Hospital",
    "UnitIcon": "./upload/file-1493206621849.png",
    "FloorId": "592254b16ea6863028aba7e2",   // unique id of another collection
    "Material_Stream_Flow_Details": [
        {
            "Stream_Flow_DetailsID": "3",
            "fa": "590042c06ea6863028aba777", 
            "fb": "590042c06ea6863028aba777",
            "fc": "590042c06ea6863028aba777",
            "fd": "590042c06ea6863028aba777",
            "fe": "590042c06ea6863028aba777",
            "ff": "590042c06ea6863028aba777",
            "_id": ObjectId("59006a8d6ea6863028aba8cb")
        }
    ],
    "Destination_Details": [
        {
            "Elevator_ID": "2",
            "Elevator": "590042c06ea6863028aba777",
            "One_way": 42.6,
            "Round_Trip": 21.3,
            "_id": ObjectId("59006a8d6ea6863028aba8cc")
        }
    ],
    "Beds_Details": [
        {
            "Beds_DetailsID": "1",
            "type1_Bed": 0,
            "type2_Bed": 0,
            "type3_Bed": 0,
            "type4_Bed": 0,
            "type5_Bed": 0,
            "type6_Bed": 0,
            "_id": ObjectId("59006a8d6ea6863028aba8cd")
        }
    ]
```

How to fetch the values to in nested collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate the `Beds_Details` array and push the `key` and `values` into another array.Please modify the array as per your requirement. I'm using the below schema to create new object:

```
{
    type: key,
    value: value
}
```

I'm using JQuery `$.each` method to iterate. 
Angular has similar method:

```
var arr = [];
angular.forEach(json, function(value, key) {
    arr.push({
        type: key,
        value: value
    });
});
```

**Demo** https://jsfiddle.net/sumitridhal/j3m2h4r0/6/

**JS**

```
var jsonObj ={ "UnitId": "59225fd86ea6863028aba8b1",    
    "UnitName": "Hospital",
    "UnitIcon": "./upload/file-1493206621849.png",
    "FloorId": "592254b16ea6863028aba7e2",   
    "Material_Stream_Flow_Details": [
        {
            "Stream_Flow_DetailsID": "3",
            "fa": "590042c06ea6863028aba777", 
            "fb": "590042c06ea6863028aba777",
            "fc": "590042c06ea6863028aba777",
            "fd": "590042c06ea6863028aba777",
            "fe": "590042c06ea6863028aba777",
            "ff": "590042c06ea6863028aba777"
        }
    ],
    "Destination_Details": [
        {
            "Elevator_ID": "2",
            "Elevator": "590042c06ea6863028aba777",
            "One_way": 42.6,
            "Round_Trip": 21.3
        }
    ],
    "Beds_Details": [
        {
            "Beds_DetailsID": "1",
            "type1_Bed": 0,
            "type2_Bed": 0,
            "type3_Bed": 0,
            "type4_Bed": 0,
            "type5_Bed": 0,
            "type6_Bed": 0,
            "_id": "59006a8d6ea6863028aba8cd"
        }
    ]};

let json = jsonObj.Beds_Details[0];
delete json['Beds_DetailsID'];
delete json['_id']; // Removes Beds_DetailsID & _id

var arr = [];
$.each(json, function(key, value){
    arr.push({
        type: key,
        value: value
    });
});
```

Comment: Here we are deleting _id's. Is a possible to get without those variables from server. I am using normal mongoose query as `collection.find({},function (err, docs) {
         res.json(docs);
     });` .

Comment: You need to define schema for that. Keep `_id : false`                        
`var subSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    //your subschema content
},{ _id : false });

var schema = mongoose.Schema({
    // schema content
    subSchemaCollection : [subSchema]
});`

Comment: I am asking while querying but not while creating.

Comment: He's adding `Name : 'Sample'` property from one object to another object.